# Cannot plot turtle pose in rqt_plot

Tags: ros, pose, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All! I am just starting to learn ROS.
So I was following the tutorial on understanding TOPICS (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics), where I was supposed to run `$ rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot` and enter `/turtle1/pose/x` in GUI, but I keep getting this message in the terminal:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 204, in on_topic_edit_textChanged
        plottable, message = is_plottable(topic_name)   File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 104, in is_plottable
        fields, message = get_plot_fields(topic_name)   File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot_widget.py", line 75, in get_plot_fields
        field_class = topic_helpers.get_type_class(slot_type) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_type_class'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_type_class'
```

I ran roswtf and got this :

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR Not all paths in PYTHONPATH [/home/omar/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages] point to a directory: 
 * /home/omar/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

No errors or warnings
```

I can't get any plots described in tutorials, so I was hoping you could help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192636/cannot-plot-turtle-pose-in-rqt_plot/) by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2014-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you have up-to-date versions of all of the ROS packages? Try running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JMarple](https://answers.ros.org/users/20192/jmarple/) on 2014-09-13**:
I was having a somewhat similar issue and this (along with restarting my computer) seemed to help, thanks!

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2014-09-15**:
Thank you, that helped!